# SQL Server : can't get join to work when using sum

Tags: sql, join, sum, aggregate

When I run this sql:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(f.flex) as flex, 
    f.anv as anvid 
FROM 
    flex f 
GROUP BY 
    f.anv
```

I'll get:

```
 anvid   | flex
 ---------------
   2     |  120
   6     |  365 
   9     |  715 
  19     | 2485 
  20     | 1545 
  21     | 1833 
  22     |  796 
  35     | 1783 
  36     |  -15 
  37     |-1582 
  38     | 1999 
  59     |  510
  70     | -275
```

Now, I want to make a join on `flex.anv` and tablecolumn `anv.id` so that I'm able to print `anv.anvnamn` (username) instead of the id as above.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(f.flex) as flex, 
    a.anvnamn as anvnamn 
FROM
    flex f 
INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN 
    anv a ON f.anv=a.id 
GROUP BY 
    f.anv
```

Then I get an error:

> Column 'anv.anvnamn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone help me? Starting to get frustrated on this...

Thanks!

Comment: add anv.anvnamn to GROUP BY clause

Comment: In your second query you changed the column in the `select` but didn't change it in the `group by` clause. If you want to select `a.anvnamn`, just change `GROUP BY f.anv` to `GROUP BY a.anvnamn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, put it in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT sum(f.flex) as flex, a.anvnamn as anvnamn
from flex f JOIN
     anv a
     ON f.anv = a.id
GROUP BY a.anvnamn;
```

Note:  if two ids have the same name, then they will be combined.  If you don't want this behavior, then use:

```
GROUP BY a.anvnamn, f.anv;
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I thought i tried that, but apparantly i didnt! :P

Answer (score 1):

Just add `a.anvnamn` to your `GROUP BY` Clause.